# Prisma vscode extension, how to access the @db namespace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, prisma

I am building a javascript/TS utility to generate a prisma schema file, for a code-first approach, and I can't seem to find out how to access the `@db` namespace, for things like `@db.UnsignedInt`. The prisma vscode extension has an autocomplete feature inside `.prisma` files, so I assume it uses some library.

Is there a package I can import in my TS file?